# Return Data from Table Column without Commas

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I'm having and issue in my SQL statment that I'm not sure how to get around.  I have column in one of the tables that have data that contains a comma.  Given this, when I save as CSV, it shifts the results due to this.  I've tried to use the CASE expression to return those results without commas.  Hers what I gotten thus far.

```
ITEMLABEL 
Order, Freight 
Purchase Charges
Inventory 
Inventory, Assets
Purchase, Discounts
```

.

```
Select ITEMLABEL=CASE
WHEN 'Order, Freight' THEN 'Order Freight'
WHEN 'Inventory, Asset' THEN "Inventory Assest'
WHEN 'Purchase, Discounts' THEN 'Purchase Discounts'
END
FROM DB_TABLE
```

What happens here is that for entries that is note Order Frieght Inventory Assets or Purchase Discounts, I get a NULL value.  Can someone help me in getting around this.  Not sure if I'm going about this the correct way as I'm fairly new to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
Select REPLACE(ITEMLABEL, ',', '') ...
```